# Add HTML entity to a WP function the_time()

Tags: php, wordpress, date, html-entities

I currently have:

```
<?php the_time('d–m–Y'); ?>
```

But this is bring up some odd glyphs, even though a charset has been set. So, how do I replace the `–` with `&ndash;`? I have tried many ways of adding them in... but no such luck.

```
<?php the_time('d&\nd\a\s\h;m&\nd\a\s\h;Y'); ?>
<?php the_time('d'&ndash;'m'&ndash;'Y'); ?>
```

I'm a little confused so apologies for my ignorance.

Comment: And what are the _odd glyphs_?

Comment: @RahilWazir – `04�04�2014`

Comment: What is your charset?

Comment: @Danny It can be used but using `the_time()` doesn't mean it won't get the correct format. If you have multiple posts on a page `the_date` will fail. [See here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_date)

Comment: @RahilWazir correct, but there is no - sign for the format the_time()
https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time 
Unless you use: str_replace("/","-",the_time('d/m/Y'));

Comment: @Danny You can use `-` sign with `the_time()`. I know the docs doesn't include in their examples. Try yourself.

Comment: @RahilWazir i have tried but it gives the same result as here in the question ... the correct date came with this: str_replace("-","/",the_time('d-m-Y'));

Comment: @rdck Try adding `-` character simply in the template file (html) and see you still get the odd glyphs?

Comment: @rdck i have just add a second possibility to display the correct date !

Answer (score 0):

try to put `:` instead of `-` and use `str_replace` to replace the `:` with `-`

Ex: `str_replace(":","-",the_time('d:m:Y'));`

I think that : won't give odd result

source : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_time

Comment: Why use `:` instead of `-`?

Comment: Because according to the source link, they used : and did not cause any problem, I know it's weird for the `-` not to work, but still can try plan B

Answer (score 0):

This gives on my site the correct values:

```
str_replace("-","/",the_time('d-m-Y'));
```

using `the_time('d–m–Y');`  gives the same result as mentioned in the question.

You can also use the following code to use the Date Format set in the admin dashboard under 
**Settings > General Settings** for either tag:

```
<?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo str_replace('-', '<span class="pln">&ndash</span>;', get_the_time('d-m-Y'));
```